# Gradle clean erasing my file prior to ZIP task execution

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have the following simple task in my build:

```
task generateFile << {
    def file = new File("$buildDir/setclasspath.sh")
    file.text = "sample"

    outputs.file(file)
}

task createDistro(type: Zip, dependsOn: ['copyDependencies','packageEnvironments','jar', 'generateFile']) <<{    
 from generateClasspathScript {
    fileMode = 0755
    into 'bin'
 }
}
```

When I run `gradle clean build` I see the following output:

```
   Cannot call TaskOutputs.file(Object) on task ':generateFile' after task has started execution. Check the configuration of task ':generateFile' as you may have misused '<<' at task declaration
```

How do I declare the task file creation outputs as an input to the zip task while also ensuring they happen in the execution phase?

If I leave off the << then the clean task wipes the generated file before the ZIP can use it. If I keep them, I get the above error.

Comment: The print statement is in the Configuration phase of the task. Use "<<" to put that block in the Execution phase of the task.

Comment: I'm having trouble, I tried adding << but then I get a problem saying that I misused it because i declared outputs.file(blah) after the execution phase has begun. updating the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use "<<" in Gradle task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071462/when-to-use-in-gradle-task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the opposite as what is being suggested in the comments. You are trying to set the outputs in execution phase. The correct way to do what you are probably trying to do is for example:

```
task generateFile {
    def file = new File("$buildDir/setclasspath.sh")
    outputs.file(file)
    doLast {
        file.text = "sample"
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Many people are confused about the Gradle phases.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense, i definitely didn't understand that doLast executes during the execution phase. But now I have the issue of createDistro being skipped as Up-To-Date even during a clean build. Shouldn't the from clause in that task mark the other as an input causing it to change