# Gradle Zip Task Up-To-Date even after clean build

Tags: gradle, groovy, zip

I have the following task definitions.

```
task generateFile {
  def file = new File("$buildDir/setclasspath.sh")
  outputs.file(file)
  doLast {
    file.text = "sample"
   }
}
```

and

```
task createDistro(type: Zip, dependsOn: ['jar', 'generateFile']) << {    
 from generateFile {
   fileMode = 0755
   into 'bin'
 }
}
```

Problem is when I run a `gradle clean build` the generateFile task runs, but the zipFile task does not.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't the clean make the input of the Zip task trigger a new run?

Comment: wait. why does generateFile run? You're not calling it in `gradle clean build`!

Comment: sorry, createDistro has a dependsOn: 'jar' as well. updated

Comment: umm `gradle clean build` still wont invoke generateFile, unless if you're explicitly calling `gradle createDistro`

Comment: ahh, i noticed this line: build.dependsOn createDistro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first understand the phases of Gradle. Mainly remember that there are CONFIG and EXECUTION phases. This was your previous problem: [Gradle clean erasing my file prior to ZIP task execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227746/gradle-clean-erasing-my-file-prior-to-zip-task-execution)

You made the same mistake in the `createDistro`. When you use the `<<` you are reducing the task to the `doLast` only and that runs in EXECUTION phase. That means your Zip task has not been configured with the `from` part. So again the correct definitions should be:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task generateFile {
  def file = new File("$buildDir/setclasspath.sh")
  outputs.file(file)
  doLast {
    file.createNewFile() // you need to actually create the file first
    file.text = "sample"
   }
}

task createDistro(type: Zip, dependsOn: ['jar', 'generateFile']) {    
// this is the configuration of Zip task, do not run it in doLast or '<<'
 from generateFile {
   fileMode = 0755
   into 'bin'
 }
}
```

Moreover as @RaGe mentioned in comments, the task won't run. You need to plug it in the task tree.

But I think you are still trying to fix a problem that you might not need to fix. From what you are doing, you might be actually better off using the [gradle distribution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) plugin.

Comment: thank you for the help, I think I get it now. Just took this example for me to put two and two together.